# I need to generate a good date and time based on laravel carbon, but I need to remove the timezone from this return

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Below is my code snippet and given return, Didn't want to remove the last characters as a string

```
$ini= Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->toAtomString();
```

return:

```
"2022-09-09T10:50:27-03:00"
```

I need:

```
2022-09-09T10:50:27
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: There are a bunch of [formatters](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-commonformats). Have you tried `toDateTimeLocalString()` instead?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
Carbon::now()->subDays(3)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```